# checkbox in form associated with Model in Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Model "Startup" and I have a other Model "Categorie". The two tables are associated.

I'd like call the data of Categoria through to form of Startup, this categories displayed with a checkbox. Inside the form Startup Form I have the categorie_id. This is the code

```
<%= form_for(@startup) do |f| %>
  <% if @startup.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@startup.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this startup from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @startup.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select :round_id, Round.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :category %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :category_id %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.collection_select :country_id, Country.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true %>
  </div>


  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>   </div> <% end %>
```

How to display the data of Categories within form with a checkboxs ?

Any idea.

pdt: My english is really bad.

Comment: Do you want to display all the available Categories with a checkbox beside it and when you submit the form it saves the `@startup` with the category associated with? (I can use French if you prefer)

Comment: Yes, I need It (I speak Spanish). Any idea How can I do this ?.

Comment: Okay first thing to know: Does a Startup can have multipltes Categories ? (have you set in the model Startup `has_many :categories` or `belongs_to :category`? Second question, do you need checkboxes or a dropdown menu (a html select with Categories as options)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If a Startup can have only one Category**, you can do like this in your view:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :category %><br />
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id , :name %>
</div>
```

This will output a dropdown menu with all the categories. Make sure that the Category model has the attribute `name`.

As you said, **a Startup belongs to one Category**, so **using radiobuttons** (checkboxes are here for multiple relation, means you could choose multiple categories):

```
<div class="field">
  <% Category.all.each do |category| %>
    <%= f.radio_button :category_id, category.id %>
    <%= f.label :category_id, category.name %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

You may have to add `<br />` tags, and html options to make it looks better.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I just each found the similar answer. How I can showing checkbox ?

Answer (score 0):

As MrYoshiji says, you can use:

It will display the category name on the screen, and the value sent will be the id.

You can find more details here : http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

I advise you to use the simple_form gem to generate your form. It's a very simple gem to use and customize ! look at it ;)